# Training a new LatentSVMDetector Models

Tags: matlab, opencv, model, training-data

I would like to train my own model to detect a different kind of object.

I don't mind do it in OpenCV or MatLab...

I already have prepared my positives and negatives samples ...
**How can I train my own model?** Where can I found documentation about that?

I want to use this new model in http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/ (MatLab or OpenCV version).

THANK YOU in advance!!

Comment: Anyone could give me any clue about how to train a DPM model to use with LatentSVM detector from my positives and negatives samples??

Answer (score 0):

Its a fair question. Navigating your way through the world of OpenCV/Matlab can be quite challenging to say the least, particularly when it comes to training models.

The page you link to has a FAQ, that FAQ says:

> Q: Can I train models with my own dataset?
>
> A: It is possible to train models using your own dataset. I recommend
>   taking a look at pascal_data.m, which defines the function that we use
>   for loading the PASCAL data into the internal data structures used by
>   our code. To support your own data, you will need to define your own
>   function that reads in your positive and negative examples
>   and returns the same data structures as the function pascal_data().

The code is also available on github, [pascal_data.m is here](https://github.com/rbgirshick/voc-dpm/blob/master/data/pascal_data.m) and the pascal_data() function is near the top of the file.
So you'll need to create your own function similar to pascal_data() that returns the same type.  Most of the method seems pretty straightforward, although to fully understand whats going on you might need a copy of the VOC2007 or VOC2010 data set.
Then take a look at [pascal_train.m](https://github.com/rbgirshick/voc-dpm/blob/master/train/pascal_train.m) it looks like you should be able to replace the call to pascal_data() with your newly created function.
Then Matlab... sorry, I haven't gotten to this point yet, so can't provide any guidance in this area.